# Selecting Optoisolator CTR for MPS MP8009 SSR Forward Topology

Tags: circuit-design, opto-isolator, poe

Do the optoisolator Current Transfer Ratio (CTR) Min and Max matter for this design, and if so, what is the benefit of selecting each ratio?

Here is the [MPS MP8009-GV PoE controller datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/277/MP8009GV_Z-2946113.pdf), inside it specifies:

> **Secondary-Side Regulation (SSR) Mode**
> The MP8009’s DC/DC controller can also be
> set to secondary-side regulation (SSR) mode.
> In SSR mode, the VOUT signal is the feedback to
> COMP pin through one optocoupler. The
> primary-side regulation (PSR) FB voltage
> detection function is disabled, so FB should be
> connected to GND.
>
> Under light-load conditions, the controller
> maintains a fixed frequency in SSR mode. If the
> COMP voltage drops, then the peak current
> drops low until it reaches the power-save mode
> (PSM) threshold. The 36mV minimum current
> limit does not work in SSR mode.
>
> In SSR mode, the DC/DC controller can support
> both flyback and forward topologies. In PSR
> mode, it can only support flyback topology.

and

> In SSR mode, the output voltage is set by
> TL431. If TL431’s reference voltage is 2.5V,
> and the expected output voltage is 12V, then
> the upper and lower divider resistor ratio is 3.8.
> Then TL431 generates an amplified signal and
> controls the DC/DC controller’s COMP pin
> through an optocoupler (e.g. PC357). COMP
> controls the current, and then VOUT is regulated
> based on the feedback signal.

Here is the exact [Sharp PC357NJ0000F optoisolator datasheet](https://global.sharp/products/device/lineup/data/pdf/datasheet/pc357n_e.pdf), it is offered with transfer ratios of 50, 80, 130, 200, and 300 % min at 5mA.